# Osgi cyclic reference needed for xstream object deserialization?

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, xstream

Bundle A depends on Bundle XStream.

However Bundle XStream also needs access to classes in Bundle A, otherwise I can't do object deserialization ala `(BundleA.class)xstream.fromXml(xmlString)`

Now what I did is to Import-Package in Bundle XStream on my BundleA packages and exported them in BundleA, but since BundleA uses XStream as well, Eclipse detects a "cyclic reference". It all seems to run fine, but I don't see the point of this Eclipse error then? 
How else would I solve this in osgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should try to get a clear client-server package relation among your bundles. So if possible at all, you should get rid of the cyclic reference. In your situation that is possible.

In contrast to what you indicate, your XStream bundle is able to do de-serialization of objects from another bundle if you are able to tell the functionality to use a different class loader for loading the classes indicated in the stream. Since it seems you are using XStream, you can use:

```
xstream.setClassLoader(bundleAClassLoader);
```

where `bundleAClassLoader` is a class loader that has access to your domain classes (the class loader of bundle A). The `Import-Package` for the XStream bundle is in that case not necessary.

Comment: this did indeed work, thank you very much! I assume most frameworks that use reflection like this, will have some kind of .setClassLoader() method

Comment: They should. If not, ignore them because of bad API design.